Ghost Blog - Unknown database error after updating the MySQL RDS database certificate on AWS
Ghost app cannot connect to AWS RDS with SSL after the RDS CA is updated to rds-ca-rsa2048-g1

What's your URL? https://vincentyuan.us/
What version of Ghost are you using? 5.54.0

And

How was Ghost installed and configured?
**It was installed on AWS, and it worked fine until recently AWS asked users to update the certificate of MySQL RDS to rds-ca-rsa2048-g1
What Node version, database, OS & browser are you using?
The instance is running on AWS EC2 (Linux), the node versions is v16.20.1, I am using MySQL RDS provided by AWS.
What errors or information do you see in the console?

ul 07 03:24:36 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]: - Inspecting operating system
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] INFO Ghost is running in production...
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] INFO Your site is now available on https://vincentyuan.us/
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] INFO Ctrl+C to shut down
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] INFO Ghost server started in 1.862s
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] INFO Bootstrap client was closed.
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] ERROR self signed certificate in certificate chain
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: 
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: "Unknown database error"
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: Error ID:
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]:     500
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: Error Code: 
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]:     HANDSHAKE_SSL_ERROR
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: ----------------------------------------
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]:     at /var/www/sitename/versions/5.54.0/node_modules/knex-migrator/lib/database.js:57:19
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]:     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/var/www/sitename/versions/5.54.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:379:42)
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]:     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]:     at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:953:8)
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]:     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:734:12)
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: 
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] WARN Ghost is shutting down
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] WARN Ghost has shut down
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] WARN Your site is now offline
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] WARN Ghost was running for a few seconds
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3768]: [2024-07-07 03:24:38] INFO Bootstrap client was closed.
Jul 07 03:24:38 ip-172-31-41-64 systemd[1]: Stopping Ghost systemd service for blog: vincentyuan-us...
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]: /usr/lib/node_modules/ghost-cli/lib/process-manager.js:46
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:         throw error;
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:         ^
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]: {
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:   message: {
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     statusCode: 500,
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     errorType: 'DatabaseError',
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     level: 'critical',
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     message: 'Ghost was able to start, but errored during boot with: self signed certificate in certificate chain',
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     id: 500,
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     help: 'Unknown database error',
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     name: 'DatabaseError',
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     code: 'HANDSHAKE_SSL_ERROR',
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     property: null,
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     redirect: null,
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     hideStack: false,
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:     fatal: true
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]:   }
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 node[3739]: }
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 systemd[1]: ghost_vincentyuan-us.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 systemd[1]: ghost_vincentyuan-us.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 07 03:24:39 ip-172-31-41-64 systemd[1]: Stopped Ghost systemd service for blog: vincentyuan-us.

below is part of the connection setup in the config:
"database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "",
      "user": "",
      "password": "",
      "database": "ghost-db",
      "ssl": "Amazon RDS"
    }
  },

I am not sure if I need to update something in the SSL part. The Ghost doc says if I use RDS, it should be good just like above, and it used to work until recently the certificate of the MySQL RDS is updated.
